# C++ Constructor for template of template

Tags: c++, templates, collections, constructor

So I have a template representing say a custom collection as follows:

```
template <typename T> class MyCollection {
    private:
        std::vector<T> v;

    public:
        MyCollection(int n) {
            v.resize(n);
        }
    etc
}
```

Now however, I want to instantiate a MyCollection of Mycollection objects, so I do this in my main program:

```
MyCollection<MyCollection<int>> mycoll= MyCollection<MyCollection<int>>(100);
```

This will indeed compile (on my MAC, using the following):

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp
```

The problem is that I get a linker error like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"std::__1::__vector_base_common<(unsigned char)1>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
  std::__1::vector<MyCollection<int>, std::__1::allocator<MyCollection<int> > >::allocate(unsigned long) in test-891fb4.o
```

What exactly is this and how do I fix it? It looks like it has something to do with a missing allocator for vector>? Why does this occur and how do I fix it?

Comment: The default C++ runtime is the GNU implementation and confusinng the linker when compile with the libc++.

Comment: So how do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp -lsupc++`? libsupc++ defines exceptions

Comment: ld: library not found for -lsupc++

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor takes one argument.  You are trying to construct the nested `MyCollection` without any arguments.  That is not possible.  You need to give a second constructor which takes an initializer for the inner collection.

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class MyCollection
{
private:
    std::vector<T> v;

public:
    explicit MyCollection(int n) : v(n) {}
    explicit MyCollection(int n,T const& init) : v(n,init) {}
};

int main()
{
    MyCollection<MyCollection<int>> mycoll(100,MyCollection<int>(1));
}
```

Instead of the initializer you can also provide a default constructor.

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class MyCollection
{
private:
    std::vector<T> v;

public:
    MyCollection() : v(0) {}
    explicit MyCollection(int n) : v(n) {}
};

int main()
{
    MyCollection<MyCollection<int>> mycoll(100);
}
```

Comment: @Marc Maybe you need to explicitly link LibC++ `clang++ -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp -lc++`

Comment: @Marc Does this help? https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html#using-libc-on-linux

Comment: If this is the problem, why did the original code get the linker error instead of an earlier compiler error?

Comment: Ok so I'm open to other suggestions

Comment: Did you test only -lc++ ? (without libc++)

Comment: clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -lc++ gives same result. I also tried using stdlib=libstdc++ and that doesn't work either

Comment: I uploaded an image to here {http://imgur.com/a/39Ya6}, may be it is an origin of your problem.

Comment: sorry doesn't hep

Answer (score 0):

Well well well, you're not going to believe this. It turns out the answer had nothing to do with the command line or libraries included. I had a *.h file of basic data types where I had this code:

```
#ifndef bool
#define bool unsigned char
#endif
```

Somehow, this messed with a prior definition of bool deep in one of the libraries, resulting in a link error that looked totally unrelated.  Anyway, it works now.

Comment: Why would you put something like this in your code?  Don't mess with the fundamental types!  If you need this for some broken API, better put something like `using bool_t = unsigned char;` and use `bool_t` instead of `bool` everywhere.